# Create a pointer that points to a member function that takes a struct as an argument

Tags: c++, class

I have main.cpp file where I defined a struct:

```
struct values {
        string name1;
        string name2;
        int key ;
        
    } a;
```

A class named **Encrypt** defined in a header file Encrypt.h and a file Encrypt.cpp where I define my functions...
Im trying to create a pointer that points to a function that has a struct type as parameter
here's how I did it:
in my header file **Encrypt.h**

```
#ifndef Encrypt_h
#define Encrypt_h
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Encrypt {
public:
    void print(void *);
};
#endif /* Encrypt_h */
```

in my **Encrypt.cpp** :

```
void Encrypt::print(void * args)
{
    struct values *a = args;
     string name= a.name1;

    cout<<"I'm"<<name<<endl;

};
```

here's how I tried to create the pointer in **main.cpp**

```
   void (Encrypt::* pointer_to_print) (void * args) = &Encrypt::print;
```

**THE ERROR I GET :**

" Cannot initialize a variable of type 'struct values *' with an lvalue of type 'void *'
"
in **Encrypt.cpp**

the line :

```
 struct values *a = args;
```

**REMARQUE**

Im doing this because I want to pass a function with more than 2 parameters to the function :
`pthread_create()`
so my function print is just I simplified example.

Comment: Unrelated: There is no need to write `struct values *a` in C++. Just write `values *a`

Comment: There is no member function in your example that takes `struct` as an argument.

Comment: `args` is of type `void*` and `a` is of type `values*` so you get the mentioned error. You can use `static_cast` to cast `args` to `values*`.

Comment: To access a member via a pointer to an object, use `->`. Eg `string name= a.name1;` becomes `string name= a->name1;`

Comment: I removed the [tag:multithreading] tag from your question. Your question is about C++ type declarations and type casting expressions. The fact that you encountered it while writing a program that uses threads does not make it a multithreading question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `args` is of type `void*` and `a` is of type `values*` so you get the mentioned error.

To solve this uou can use `static_cast` to cast `args` to `values*` if you're sure that the cast is allowed:

```
values *a = static_cast<values*>(args);
```

Additionally change `a.name1` to `a->name1`.

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ljcg_G1X_)

Comment: I changed `struct values *a = args; ` with `values *a = static_cast<values*>(args);` and now Im getting this error **Unknown type name 'values'**  I saw your demo, but still not working for me, is it because Im using OOP ( multiple files )

Comment: @HamzaDevXX Did you forget to add `struct values {string name1;string name2;int key;} .a;` ? That's why i gave a link to [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ljcg_G1X_) in my answer. You can copy/paste the code from there and if you get any error you can match and see what part you have different from the working demo and then correct it accordingly.

Comment: I tried to also add my struct : 
    `struct values {  string name1;  string name2;  int key ; };` to the header file and now it's working :) thank you so much :)

Comment: btw why is it important ?  isn't declaring my struct **values**  just in main.cpp enought ?

Comment: Because you're writing `a->name1` so compiler needs its definition and not just its declaration.